# Swift: Why use a function that doesn't return..?

Tags: ios, swift, function, swift3

I'm sure this question must have been asked 100s of times before, but, what are the most famous scenarios in which I use a function (with everything that come with it -parameters, logic inside the function-), then I wouldn't need to return anything..? Why is that function sitting inside my code, then..?

If I may put it differently, what benefit do I get from a function that does something -or somethings-, then doesn't provide me with some feedback or a result of its execution..?

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Do you think `print(...)` should return something and why?

Comment: I think this may help if I understand what you said: example if you have a student object with empty date and empty ID, and you want to set a date and ID for that student, why would you return a value while you just want to set those values for Student Object, While when you need to access those values you create a Get function that returns ID:String for example without affecting its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe my problem was trying to understand the purpose of functions in Swift from a procedural point of view. When I learned PL programming, I was taught that functions return values, and the ones that don't return values are called procedures. Now, 3 months into learning Swift, my view is way clearer as to how it's being used in Swift, and OOP.

Answer (score 1):

This mostly depends on the reason, which caused the programmer to encapsulate the code in an function/method. If it is an asynchronously executed method, for example, there wouldn't be a result an just the moment someone calls the method.